# Json string format with double quotes

Tags: jquery, json

Is there any function like json.parse or stringify which creates a valid json format.

I have string in this format 
"{'EncryptionType':'aa', 'EncryptionKey':'bb', 'EncryptionDone' :'cc'}"

and I am trying to convert to valid json format.

like  "{"EncryptionType":"aa"", "EncryptionKey":"bb", "EncryptionDone" :"cc"}"

[myfiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/5o5a4znf/1/)

```
var details = "{'EncryptionType':'aa', 'EncryptionKey':'bb', 'EncryptionDone' :'cc'}"
var updatedDetails = JSON.stringify(details);

alert(updatedDetails);

string FinalResult = "{"EncryptionType":"aa"", "EncryptionKey":"bb", "EncryptionDone" :"cc"}"
```

Comment: why not just string replace all of the single quotes to double quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `details` string is already in valid JSON format; JSON can use either single or double quotes for key/value pairs.  Paste it into [jsonlint.com](http://www.) and see for yourself.

If you're getting errors of some sort, it's for a different reason.

Note: your `FinalResult` variable isn't valid JSON as it has two double quotes after `aa`.

Answer (score 1):

I tested and its works;

```
var details = "{'EncryptionType':'aa', 'EncryptionKey':'bb', 'EncryptionDone' :'cc'}"

var updatedDetails = eval('('+details+')');

alert(updatedDetails.EncryptionType)
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ltj0u12z/)

Comment: ib4 the eval is terrible spam

Comment: remove this line; -- string FinalResult = "{"EncryptionType":"aa"", "EncryptionKey":"bb", "EncryptionDone" :"cc"}"